# Using credentials with Active Directory object picker

Tags: active-directory, credentials

I'm trying to use the Active Directory Object Picker by having an IP, user, and pwd where the AD data is on the IP machine, and the user/pwd is a domain user.

I can connect, and use Advanced to see names of users and groups.

But I don't get the group ID (objectGuid) in the result data.

I see there is an `IDsObjectPickerCredentials` which looks like it might be the way forward.

But I can't find any detail documentation or examples on it with C++.

Anyone have an example in C++, or documentation on using that object?

I have tried the directory picker with an IP, and it allowed navigating to a group, but it did not return the objectGuid of that group

Comment: Showing your code would help. Are you including `objectGuid` in the `apwzAttributeNames` parameter of the [`DSOP_INIT_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objsel/ns-objsel-dsop_init_info) struct passed into [`IDsObjectPicker::Initialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objsel/nf-objsel-idsobjectpicker-initialize)?